# Evaluating $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{2017}\dfrac 1{n^2+2n}$

Tags: summation

I tried simplifying it by first resolving it into partial fractions but to no use. Also I know that $\sum (1/n)$ is harmonic number, but I don't know how to use it. Please help me.

Comment: $\sum_{n=1}^{2017}\frac{1}{n^{2}+2n}=\sum_{n=1}^{2017}\frac{1}{n(n+2)}=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{2017}\left(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+2}\right)$. Note that this is telescoping.

Comment: Well thanks for that last expression.... I'll try singing with it.... Else please help me

Comment: This may help:$$\sum_{n=1}^{2017}\frac{1}{n+2}=\sum_{n=3}^{2019}\frac{1}{n}$$ What does the expression "singing with it" mean? I've never heard that before.

Comment: "singing with it", sorry for this...I wanted to type "something with it", but since I use glide typing I might have pressed the wrong buttons.

Comment: @LokeshSangewar LOL singing with it...

Comment: But then again sigma 1/n n=3 to 2019.....How to go ahead with this....Coz I want the answer as a single rational

Comment: $$\sum_{n=1}^{2017}\left(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+2}\right)=\sum_{n=1}^{2017}\frac{1}{n}-\sum_{n=3}^{2019}\frac{1}{n}$$ Note that many terms cancel.

Comment: Okkkk....I got it. Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: @LokeshSangewar No problem.

Comment: But dude....(1/n)-(1/n+2) is not equal to 1/n(n+2).....So how to do it???????

Comment: @Servaes nope......I don't think so

Comment: @Servaes Did I make an error? I'd be happy to delete my comments if this has happened.

Comment: @user71352 well.... Unfortunately yes

Comment: @LokeshSangewar Oh shoot! Can you point me to the error?

Comment: U wrote 1/n(n+2) as 1/n - 1/n+2.....That's wrong.....

Comment: @LokeshSangewar I gather, perhaps incorrectly, you are referring to my first comment. I believe there is a factor of $\frac{1}{2}$ on the outside of the sum and $$\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+2}\right)=\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{(n+2)-n}{n(n+2)}=\frac{1}{n(n+2)}$$

Comment: @user71352 You didn't. I was snidely commenting on the fact that your first three comments very explicitly give a step by step answer, yet the OP asks a question with an extremely obvious answer that above all you already gave. The OP's homework has now been done without any understanding from his/her side, which bothers me. But expressing this in such a way might not be helpful, so I'll delete my comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{2017}\dfrac 1{n^2+2n}=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^{2017}(\frac {1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+2})$

Writing it out:

$\frac{1}{2}[1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+...+\frac{1}{2016}+\frac{1}{2017}$

$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ -(\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+...+\frac{1}{2016}+\frac{1}{2017}+\frac{1}{2018}+\frac{1}{2019})]$

$=\frac{1}{2}(1+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2018}-\frac{1}{2019})$

Comment: I could be mistaken but I think there should be negatives on $\frac{1}{2018}$ and $\frac{1}{2019}$.

Comment: Yh that's correct.... They're negative

Comment: Well I have posted another question....It has not been answered yet....Well if anyone can help me with that

Comment: @user71352 Rectified. Thanks.

Comment: @WiCK3DPOiSON No problem. (+1)